# Rewriting URL with special characters

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a bunch of crawl errors on my site to pages that don't exist (and never existed). It was created from some bad code that generated JSON-LD schema.org for a search page. Basically, I have thousands of 404s that look like this

```
http://www.domain.com/search/%7Bsearch_term%7D%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F3%2Fpage%2F6%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F3%2Fpage%2F6%2Fpage%2F6%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F3%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F6%2Fpage%2F3%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F6%2Fpage%2F3%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F7%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F8%2Fpage%2F3
http://www.domain.com/search/%7Bsearch_term%7D%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F6%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F3%2Fpage%2F6%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F6%2Fpage%2F6%2Fpage%2F6%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F3%2Fpage%2F3%2Fpage%2F3%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F3%2Fpage%2F7%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F7%2Fpage%2F2%2Fpage%2F8%2Fpage%2F3
```

I am terrible with regex, and could use some help on figuring out how to resolve this. As a short term solution, I just want to redirect URL requests with /search/{search_term}/ in the URL to just the /search page.

Any tips on what I should be doing? This is what I have been messing around with which is obviously wrong. Sorry if this is terribly easy question, but I've been trying different things I find online, and have just beating my head without success.

```
RewriteRule ^/search/%7Bsearch_term%7D$ /search [R,L=301]
RewriteRule ^/search/\{search_term\}$ /search [R,L=301]
```

Comment: is search_term a placeholder for a word or is that the literal words appearing in the URL?

Comment: It's supposed to be a placeholder, like this {search_term}. It's from the Yoast SEO plugin, they have this JSON-LD search feature. Apparently for many months, it was returning a status 200, but since the site in question was updated to Wordpress 4.1, those URLs started returning a 404. I only know this b/c I went back through the logs trying to figure out the deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close. You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^search/\{search_term\} /search [R,L=302,NC]
```

Or if `search_term` is also a dynamic string then use:

```
RewriteRule ^search/\{[^}]+\} /search [R,L=302,NC]
```

---

**EDIT:** You will need this directive in your Apache or vhost config:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

otherwise Apache rejects requests with these special characters without giving you any chance to handle them in `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Both of them worked in my test. What's your Apache version? Make sure these are very first rules in your root .htaccess

Comment: Check my **EDIT** section.

Comment: Apache 2.2.29. And I just moved it to the first line in my root .htaccess file. File permissions is 644

Comment: AllowEncodedSlashes helped do the trick. That's great to know, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head, this should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^search\/(.+) http://www.yourdomain.com/search [R=302]
```

Explanation of the syntax above:

`^` indicates the start of the match

`\` is the escape character, so `\/` means *escape the forward slash* (probably unnecessary, but does no harm)

`()` is a capture group

`.` means *any character*

`+` means *one or more of*

So the whole regex means:

starting at the current position in the folder hierarchy, match

***search/***

followed by one or more characters.

**N.B.** Importantly, it is the `R` flag which indicates the type of redirect, so you need `R=302`, (not `L=302`, which doesn't exist)

Comment: I tried this rule as well, but I still get the 404. At first it made me wonder that mod_rewrite wasn't working properly, but I turned on the RewriteLogLevel=3, and checked the log. It shows other rules firing, but not this one.